# subtract same variables in single object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
const token = [
  {"token":"d2r4Z62OTGiPyNmdHTUfny",
  "time":1652767811},
  {"token":"dnl13twkQIqifdvaxp1t6e",
  "time":1652767811},
  {"token":"eDZxQu0FSWm72D2-T1md5X",
  "time":1652767811},
  {"token":"dnl13twkQIqifdvaxp1t6e",
  "time":1652767811}]; // Try edit me
  const arr = [];
  for (var i=0; i<=token.length-1; i++)
  {
    const millis = Date.now();
    const time  = Math.floor(millis / 1000);
    if (token[i].time > time) {
      arr.push(token[i].token)
    }
   }
   console.log(arr);
```

between these two token variables are the same, I want to distinguish them from each other, how can I do that?
Example Output:

```js
const example = [
  "d2r4Z62OTGiPyNmdHTUfny",
  "eDZxQu0FSWm72D2-T1md5X",
  "dnl13twkQIqifdvaxp1t6e"
];
console.log(example);
```

Comment: you mean extracting unique token keys ? what's the purpose of 'time' ? try array.reduce

Comment: Use a `Set` to eliminate duplicates.

Comment: timestamp is not so important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) as it doesn't allow for duplicates:

```js
const tokens = [
  {"token":"d2r4Z62OTGiPyNmdHTUfny", "time":1652767811},
  {"token":"dnl13twkQIqifdvaxp1t6e", "time":1652767811},
  {"token":"eDZxQu0FSWm72D2-T1md5X", "time":1652767811},
  {"token":"dnl13twkQIqifdvaxp1t6e", "time":1652767811}
];

const now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
const result = new Set(
  tokens.filter(({ time }) => time > now).map(({ token }) => token)
);

console.log(...result);
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way with your current logic is that you can use `includes` to check `token` with the `arr` results. If it's in `arr`, we don't need to push it to `arr`.

```js
const token = [
  {"token":"d2r4Z62OTGiPyNmdHTUfny",
  "time":1652767811},
  {"token":"dnl13twkQIqifdvaxp1t6e",
  "time":1652767811},
  {"token":"eDZxQu0FSWm72D2-T1md5X",
  "time":1652767811},
  {"token":"dnl13twkQIqifdvaxp1t6e",
  "time":1652767811}];
  const arr = [];
  for (var i=0; i<=token.length-1; i++)
  {
    const millis = Date.now();
    const time  = Math.floor(millis / 1000);
    if (!arr.includes(token[i].token) && token[i].time > time) {
      arr.push(token[i].token)
    }
   }
   console.log(arr);
```